# The ViewData item that has the key 'Catagory_id' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

this is the table that have a relation with Category_id as you can see

[image]

and im using entity framework so you can see the class

[image]

this is my edit (get)controller

[image]

when i run my application it gives me this error on dropdownlist

[image]

i want to retrieve category_name data from the catalog_categories to show which product belongs to which category. need help

Comment: Try following:

<%= Html.DropDownList("Category_id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Category_id"]) %>
?

Comment: thanks for your reply faizanrabbani  but i have tried that before it still giving me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `DropDownList` helper to render a SELECT element like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category_Id",null,new { @class="form-control"})
```

The helper method looks for an item called `Category_Id` in the ViewBag dictionary and if it is there and it has a list of `SelectListItem`'s, the helper will be able to render the SELECT element options from that collection.

So let's say if action method has code like below before calling the `return View()` statement

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Category 1"},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Category 2"},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Category 3"},
};
ViewBag.Category_Id = list;
```

The SELECT element will be rendered using the 3 `SelectListItem` objects we passed to `ViewBag.Category_Id`.

Now in your case, it is the edit screen and you do not have a view model, what you have to do is explcitily specify a different collection in your `DropDownList` helper method overload.

Like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category_Id",ViewBag.CategoryList as List<SelectListItem>
                                                       ,new { @class="form-control"})
```

For this code to work, we need to make sure that we are setting a list in the action method to `ViewBag.CategoryList`

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Category 1"},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Category 2", Selected = true},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Category 3"},
};
ViewBag.CategoryList= list;
```

You can replace the hard coded SelectListItem with the data from your table. Something like this (update your class/property names as needed)

```
var categoryId=cat_product.Catagory_id;
var list = db.CatalogCategories
                  .Select(a=>new SelectListItem { 
                                            Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                                            Text=a.Category_Name, 
                                            Selected = ( categoryId!=null && 
                                                                categoryId.Value==a.Id)
                         })
            .ToList();
```

While this might fix the issue, You have another (more clean and readable and clean ) option of using a view model along with the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method. I strongly recommend that approach. You can find of tons of sample on SO for that approach.

Comment: Thnak you so much Shyju, i was stuck for like 8 hours for this logic and you make it look so easy but thanks man your great (y) :D